# INDIRECT function inside countifs

Tags: google-sheets

I have this function:

```
=countifs(('Form Responses 1'!$H$2):('Form Responses 1'!$H$2888),$A$1,('Form Responses 1'!$M$2):('Form Responses 1'!$M$2888),D$1)
```

And I was trying to make something like this:

```
=countifs(=INDIRECT("('Form Responses 1'!$"&A1&"$2)"):('Form Responses 1'!$H$2888),$A$1,('Form Responses 1'!$M$2):('Form Responses 1'!$M$2888),D$1)
```

But it doesn't work and I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevemind! I was able to make it work:

```
=countifs(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!$"&N1&"$2"):('Form Responses 1'!$J$2888),$A$1,('Form Responses 1'!$L$2):('Form Responses 1'!$L$2888),C$1)
```